# Loopback on T1 not showing up

Tags: cisco-ios, loopback

I'm a T1 tech for a major US ISP. We regularly remotely loopback T1s (at the smartjack) and test them before the installation. Recently I got 3 new T1s in a bundle that acted weird, and I hoping you guys could tell me what's going on.

This issue is on a Cisco GSR Router.

When I looped up the T1s and checked the interface with `sh int status Serial0/11/2/12:1`, it was down/down instead of expected `interface is up, line protocol is down(looped)`.

Now, sometimes I do find the interface turns to `up/down` but the router doesn't show `(looped)`, although I don't know why. Everything else works properly in such cases, so it's not a major issue. This time, L1 and L2 status stayed down, and of course all pings to a loopback failed.

I manually tried providing a 1-way loop at a digital access cross connect, and the interface changed status to up/down. I normalized the circuit, i.e., returned it to its original state, and the circuit went back to down/down.

Now, we have a proprietary piece of software that attaches a separate BERT test card on the T1 to test T1s, and it was able to loop up the T1s and showed the data being passed to the T1 was returning via the loopback without errors, i.e., the soft loop existed and worked properly.

I created a ticket with the LEC for a prove to demarc, and they provided a hard loop. On this as expected, the packets passed without drops and the interface status was up/down.

Why can't the router detect a soft loop? Why are pings failing over it? Am I doing something wrong?!

Comment: Interface (router) configuration?

Comment: If the interface is down/down, then you're probably not receiving clock, or your router is misconfigured.

Comment: @RonTrunk However the same tests pass when a hard loop is provided. We use a tool that configures the interface IP to 192.168.1.1/31 and essentially pings itself via the loopback. It works in all other cases but this. Since it's already configured as the DCE it should be self clocking, which is why it works normally.

Comment: Did someone turn off `keepalive` on the port?